# What is the Ada equivalent of #define in C++?

Tags: ada

I'm new to Ada and as far as I could explore on the internet, I was unable to find an analog to this C++ concept.

Say I have `package_name.data_member` (multiple variables in various packages). I'm hoping to shorten that to a more reader-friendly manner like below (without using the `Use` keyword) because those variables will be used multiple times in the same file -

```
#define A package_name.data_member
#define B package_name.data_member
...
```

Is there a way I can do the above in Ada?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you need an object renaming declaration ([ARM 8.5.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-8-5-1.html#S0200)):

```ada
A : Data_Member_Type renames Package_Name.Data_Member;
```

---

If you’re using GNAT, it includes a tool [gnatprep](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_ugn/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#preprocessing-with-gnatprep); the major differences from `cpp` are that

- symbols to be substituted have to be marked in the source text, e.g.`$foo`(`$` isn’t in the Ada source character set),
- substitutions can only be defined in a separate definitions file (or e.g `-Dfoo=bar` on the command line).

Answer (score 4):

There is no exact analogue of #define (or any pre-processing) in standard Ada (although you could use a macro preprocessor if you need that), but for this use a renaming declaration should suit:

A : Atype renames package_name.data_memberA;

B : Btype renames package_name.data_memberB;

This has the advantage, over #define, that the tokens A and B are not mistakenly replaced by their #defines in unintended places.